# angularjs ng-repeat adding html comments on dom

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Why does angularjs cause multiple comments in between render data? Inspecting DOM childNodes causes extra nodes which takes up memory. Is there a way to remove them?

[image]

Comment: This is annoying to me as I find the need to do this

angular.element(document.getElementById('modal')).append($compile(templates[type])(scope));

then try and remove the stuff that got added except that its no longer so clean and easy.

I am so annoyed that I have to revert to javascript directly to manipulate the dom for dynamic templates, it is wrong keeps feeling wrong but it seems there is no other way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular needs these comments to operate with some directives. Removing those comments breaks Angular and it is not allowed to do so currently.

It is also explained in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8722) Github issue.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses the comments do figure out where the last element was placed in relation. It's here in the source code https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/9efa46ae640cde17487c341daa9a75c0bd79da02

The comments are written client-side so there's no impact on transfer, and if your application is that memory conservative, Angular is probably the wrong language to use in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I find these comments annoying too. You can turn off the content of them though. Just set `debugInfoEnabled` to `false` in the config:

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```